# Hard drive not powering

Tags: hard-drive, troubleshooting, sata, forensics

I've got a SATA hard drive attached to a forensic write blocker (**Tableau e35u**), but the drive will not be recognized. This is because I can't power the write blocker when the drive is attached. The power light is on, but I cannot start the write blocker itself.

To clarify here, the data connection seems fine. If I just have that connection attached, the blocker powers on. Attaching the SATA power connection cuts out the blocker.

I tested the drive with another write blocker (**Wiebetech Forensic Combodock v5**), and again no luck. The Wiebetech blocker flashes the power light on and off.

The USB port for the host computer is fine. The write blockers work fine with other drives.

So, it would seem the drive (logic board, motor, or something else?) is the problem.

Does this analysis sound sane? If so, is there anything I can do myself to get this drive readable again? Data recovery services are not a likely option, as this data is probably duplicated elsewhere, and it'd ultimately be cheaper to go that route.

Comment: Post the manual for this device

Comment: [Here are the docs](http://www.hgst.com/tech/techlib.nsf/products/Deskstar_p7k500) on the drive. Model HDP725050GLA360.